# iOS - Unresolved error causes crash: Dangling reference to an invalid object

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5

I get the following crash on iOS:

```
    Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)" UserInfo=0x74a30d0 {NSValidationErrorObject=<Exercise: 0x9097d50> (entity: Exercise; id: 0x9097970 <x-coredata://AF762754-4CD9-4386-A453-049CC8710DBF/Exercise/p124> ; data: {
    groupId = 21;
    id = 102;
    intensity = "0x906a7a0 <x-coredata://AF762754-4CD9-4386-A453-049CC8710DBF/Intensity/p125>";
    lengthMeasurable = 1;
    name = Running;
    owner = "0x9096540 <x-coredata:///ExerciseEvent/t6817E9A9-9A4C-4044-BF20-FC15380B7C2F4>";
    picId = 2719;
}), NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=(
    "<ExerciseEvent: 0x9090910> (entity: ExerciseEvent; id: 0x9096540 <x-coredata:///ExerciseEvent/t6817E9A9-9A4C-4044-BF20-FC15380B7C2F4> ; data: <fault>)"
), Dangling reference to an invalid object.=null, NSValidationErrorKey=owner, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.), NSValidationErrorValue=<ExerciseEvent: 0x9090910> (entity: ExerciseEvent; id: 0x9096540 <x-coredata:///ExerciseEvent/t6817E9A9-9A4C-4044-BF20-FC15380B7C2F4> ; data: <fault>)}, {
    "Dangling reference to an invalid object." = "<null>";
    NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey =     (
        "<ExerciseEvent: 0x9090910> (entity: ExerciseEvent; id: 0x9096540 <x-coredata:///ExerciseEvent/t6817E9A9-9A4C-4044-BF20-FC15380B7C2F4> ; data: <fault>)"
    );
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)";
    NSValidationErrorKey = owner;
    NSValidationErrorObject = "<Exercise: 0x9097d50> (entity: Exercise; id: 0x9097970 <x-coredata://AF762754-4CD9-4386-A453-049CC8710DBF/Exercise/p124> ; data: {\n    groupId = 21;\n    id = 102;\n    intensity = \"0x906a7a0 <x-coredata://AF762754-4CD9-4386-A453-049CC8710DBF/Intensity/p125>\";\n    lengthMeasurable = 1;\n    name = Running;\n    owner = \"0x9096540 <x-coredata:///ExerciseEvent/t6817E9A9-9A4C-4044-BF20-FC15380B7C2F4>\";\n    picId = 2719;\n})";
    NSValidationErrorValue = "<ExerciseEvent: 0x9090910> (entity: ExerciseEvent; id: 0x9096540 <x-coredata:///ExerciseEvent/t6817E9A9-9A4C-4044-BF20-FC15380B7C2F4> ; data: <fault>)";
}
```

And I get this crash at a certain point, and that is when I want to save my model `ExerciseEvent` in `CoreData`. So I create in my view a new entity like this: 
`self.ee = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExerciseEvent" inManagedObjectContext:context]`

Then I have 2 buttons, "Save" and "Discard". If I press "Discard" I have to remove the entity so I don't get a nullable `ExerciseEvent` in the context. I delete it in this way in the view:

```
[context deleteObject:self.ee];
[context save:nil];
```

Then when I open my list of all `ExerciseEvents` i get the following crash as described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually arises because a relationship is set improperly often when an Excercise object is left without a necessary reciprocal relationship to ExerciseEvent. You are trying to delete object ExerciseEvent. 
And Exercise object has relation with this ExerciseEvent and cannot have null relation with this, but when you are removing ExerciseEvent, there will appear an error.
The object is "dangling" because the object graph says it should be in a relationship but it is just hanging off in space unconnected to any other object.

---

So what you need to do is to set correct Relationship Delete Rule between objects ExerciseEvent and Exercise. There should be Cascade Rule. You can find details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Comment: Thanks mate, that was it! I had no action on delete in CoreData, I changed it to Cascade :)